# Python smtp can't send mail to group email address

Tags: python, smtp

My smtplib code:

```
import sys
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText

SMTP_SERVER = "mailserver.company.com"
SMTP_PORT = 25

def send_mail(mail_subject, mail_from, mail_to, mail_cc, mail_message, mail_priority="Normal"):
    mime=MIMEText(mail_message, "html", "utf-8")
    mime["Subject"]=mail_subject
    mime["From"]=mail_from
    mime["To"]=', '.join(mail_to)
    mime["CC"]=', '.join(mail_cc)
    mime['X-Priority'], mime['X-MSMail-Priority'] = transfer_smtp_priority(mail_priority)
    email=mime.as_string()

    try:
        smtp=None
        smtp=smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)
        smtp.ehlo()
        smtp.starttls()
        smtp.sendmail(mime["From"], mail_to + mail_cc, email)
    finally:
        if smtp != None:
            smtp.quit()

def transfer_smtp_priority(priority):
    if priority == "Normal":
        return '''3''', '''Normal'''
    elif priority == "Low":
        return '''5''', '''Low'''
    elif priority == "High":
        return '''1''', '''High'''
        
send_mail("TEST", "DAN.W@company.com", ["DAN2.W@company.com"], ["mail.group@company.com", "DAN.W@company.com"],  "Test mail for python smtp module")
```

The personal email address can receive this test mail but the user exist in group email can't.
Is there any solution to resolved it...

Comment: Hi, 

Have you resolved this?

Comment: I haven't resolved this problem...

Comment: What do you mean by "user exists in group"? This sounds like a server-side problem (I'm guessing you are an Exchange victim), not directly a code problem. Please [edit] to provide debugging details.

Comment: As an aside, your code seems to be written for Python 3.5 or earlier. The `email` library was overhauled in 3.6 and is now quite a bit more versatile and logical. Probably throw away what you have and start over with the [examples from the `email` documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.examples.html)